# How to make a Bootstrap nav link clickable to redirect to a new URL on desktop, but clickable to expand the accordion menu on mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to swap the functionality of Bootstrap's accordion menu navigation links out on smaller screens. I think that's the most accurate way for me to describe it, but i could be wrong here.

I currently have this, for a navbar:

```
    <header>
<!--Navigation
------------------------------------------------------------------------>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top bg-white navbar-boxshadow mt-sm-5 mt-5 pt-0">
    <div class="container">
        <!--Navigation Logotype-->
        <a class="navbar-brand pr-4" href="/" alt="Link to Home Page">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="images/navigation/logo.svg" />
        </a>
        <!--Navigation Hamburger Menu (Smaller Screens)-->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
            aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <!--Navigation Links-->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <!--Navigation Links (Left)-->
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown-02" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Top Navigation Link</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-02">
                        <!---->
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Accordion Menu Link 01<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Accordion Menu Link 01.A</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Accordion Menu Link 01.B</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Accordion Menu Link 01.C</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!---->
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Accordion Menu Link 02<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Accordion Menu Link 02.A</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Accordion Menu Link 02.B</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!---->
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Accordion Menu Link 03<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Accordion Menu Link 03.A</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Accordion Menu Link 03.B</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- -->
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Accordion Menu Link 04<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Accordion Menu Link 04.A</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Accordion Menu Link 04.B</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- -->
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Accordion Menu Link 05</a>
                            <!--
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!---->
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-0">
                <li class="nav-item d-none d-xs-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-inline-block d-xl-inline-block">
                    <a class="nav-link font-icon" href="#" title=""><span class="d-none d-xs-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-none d-lg-inline-block d-xl-inline-block"><img alt="" title="" src="" /></span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item d-none d-xs-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-inline-block d-xl-inline-block">
                    <a class="nav-link font-icon" href="" title=""><span class="d-none d-xs-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-none d-lg-inline-block d-xl-inline-block"><img alt="" title="" src="" /></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And what i'd like to do, is to have the first level of accordion menu (for example, **Accordion Menu Link 01**, as i have labelled it above) items be clickable to drive to new URLs - but only on desktop devices. The first level of accordion menu items have hover functionality on larger screens at present, to reveal the second level of accordion menu items when rolled over.

But - i'd like these same first level accordion menu items to open the second level of accordion menu items on **press** on mobile devices. I can then try to add a new menu item below a certain breakpoint for these screens that will get the user to the  link that works on click on large screens.

It may be easier to link to something that currently visualises how this should ideally work, an example of which i have found at https://www.node4.co.uk. The *services* menu item under the main navigation provides a working example of what i would ideally like to achieve.

Big love in advance to anybody who can tell me this is a quick fix and i'm just being dense.

Comment: You need to hide and show essentially two seperate copies of the clickable, one which expands and one which redirects

Comment: Use `d-none` and `d-xx-block` to control the link on different display sizes?

Comment: Yes, that is the only way else look for a js solution